# Problema al intentar centrar texto en juego Wordle en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Saludos a la comunidad de Stack Overflow,

Estoy desarrollando un juego Wordle en JavaScript y estoy experimentando dificultades al intentar centrar el texto en la interfaz del juego. Actualmente, estoy utilizando CSS para estilizar mi página, pero parece que no estoy logrando centrar el texto correctamente.

Aquí está el código relevante:
[Archivo #css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uLpE.png)[image: Archivo #html]

Comment: Por favor, añade tu código como texto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting